# Return text from XML query - Python

Tags: python, xml

I need the return of an XML query with SOAP to be in XML format, but it only returns a line of text without indentation, and with the tags (< and >) changed to &alt and & gt

```py
import requests

url = ''
xml = """<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ss2=\"http://tempuri.org/SS20WS\">
               <soapenv:Header/>
               <soapenv:Body>
                  <ss2:Consulta>
                     <ss2:XML><![CDATA[<CONFIE><CONSULTA DOCUMENTO="XXXXXXX" UF=""
                                LOGIN="XXXXXX" SENHA="XXXXX" TIPOCONSULTA="1" TIPORELATORIO="1"
                                TIPORETORNO="1" TIPODOCUMENTO="1" TIMEOUT="20000" DIAS="180" HTML="N" RECEITA="S">
                                </CONSULTA><MONITORE PERIODOMONIT="" EMAILMONIT=""
                                REFERENCIAMONIT=""></MONITORE></CONFIE>]]>
                     </ss2:XML>
                  </ss2:Consulta>
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>"""
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}

r = requests.post(url, data=xml, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Excerpt from the response I receive:

```
&lt;NO_MUNICIPIO&gt;JAU&lt;/NO_MUNICIPIO&gt;&lt;CEP&gt;17210170&lt;/CEP&gt;&lt;IBGE&gt;3525300&lt;/IBGE&gt;&lt;IBGE-DISTRITO&gt;
```

Comment: A naÏve approach could be to just replace those values with what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "right" way to do this but it seems to work:

```
from lxml import etree

CONTROL = {
    '&amp;': '&',
    '&#38;': '&',
    '&#60;': '<',
    '&lt;': '<',
    '&#62;': '>',
    '&gt;': '>',
    '&#39;': "'",
    '&apos;': "'",
    '&#34;': '"',
    '&quot;': '"',
    '&nbsp;': ' '
}
def fix_xml(xml):
    for k, v in CONTROL.items():
        xml = xml.replace(k, v)
    return xml

XML = """&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;"""

fxml = fix_xml(XML)
print(fxml)
etree.fromstring(fxml)
```

**Note:**

The etree import is used here just to validate the modified XML

**Output:**

```
<head></head>
```

Comment: Hello!! thanks for help.
But I still have a problem.
When you put the variable 'r' to be decoded in the function you passed me, it returns an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/amaranta.lino/PycharmProjects/cad_fornecedor/teste_xml.py", line 40, in <module>
    fxml = fix_xml(r)
  File "C:/Users/amaranta.lino/PycharmProjects/cad_fornecedor/teste_xml.py", line 35, in fix_xml
    xml = xml.replace(k, v)
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: fxml = fix_xml(r)
print(fxml)
etree.fromstring(fxml)

Comment: r is a response object. If you re-read my answer you will notice that fix_xml takes a string as its parameter. Try fix_xml(r.text)

Comment: It worked, because the tags are correct now!! But with an error message, do you know if it's possible to fix it?  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/amaranta.lino/PycharmProjects/cad_fornecedor/teste_xml.py", line 42, in <module>
    etree.fromstring(fxml)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3254, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1908, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration."

Comment: It is absolutely NOT the right way to do it, but I don't understand the question well enough to suggest anything better.

Comment: @MichaelKay Please let us know the "right" way. Thanks

Comment: @guri_da_ti I suggest you research "Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported" in the context of parsing XML. Unfortunately we don't have access to your complete XML so it's hard to give a definitive answer

Comment: My intention is that the answer to my query comes in XML formatting. As in the example of this link: https://acervolima.com/fazer-chamadas-de-api-soap-usando-python/

Comment: Sorry, I can't help any further, I can only give a high-level architectural view of what's wrong, but it would need too much effort to dive into the detail to find exactly where the problem occurs in your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The extract you posted doesn't explain clearly where the response is coming from, but what you could do is parse the string to make it an ElementTree and navigate it as that:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def process_xml(value):
    value = value.replace('&gt;', '>')
    value = value.replace('&lt;', '<')
    value = f"<xml>{value}</xml>"
    return ET.fromstring(value)

process_xml(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you're receiving has been "double-escaped". At some stage it was a normal XML message `<NO_MUNICIPIO>JAU</NO_MUNICIPIO>` and then someone inserted this XML message as text into a wrapper XML document, which caused it to be escaped with the `&lt;...&gt;` stuff. Now, that might or might not be a good design, but what matters now is how the text is extracted. If you parse the wrapper document using an XML parser, you will find there is a text node containing the unescaped content, `<NO_MUNICIPIO>JAU</NO_MUNICIPIO>`, and you can pass this into a second XML parser to process it. If you're seeing the `&lt;...&gt;` escape sequences, that means that somewhere along the line, someone is reading XML without using an XML parser, because an XML parser will always convert `&lt;` to `<`. And reading XML without using an XML parser is always bad news.

Comment: Hi! Do you know any parser for XML? Because whenever I'm going to print the return, it implies using .text, I've tried using .xml but it's not possible.

Comment: My intention is that the answer to my query comes in XML formatting. As in the example of this link: https://acervolima.com/fazer-chamadas-de-api-soap-usando-python/